# Using a ts_vector column for a text search

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, tsvector

Hard to find out information about this `ts_vector` thing, but for the purposes of speeding up an address search, a simple index on the address column doesn't really give satisfying results.

To circumvent this limitation I'm trying to to use the `ts_vector` with the following query:

```
alter table mytable add tsv ts_vector;

update mytable set tsv = to_tsvector(address);
```

I'm very unfamiliar with this `ts_vector` column but would it speed things if I created a btree index (or any other index) and instead of querying the address column to query the `ts_vector` column instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it has to be a GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable USING gin (tsv);
```

You don't need to add that extra column, you can also do:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable USING gin (to_tsvector('english', address));
```

Such an index can be used with the `@@` operator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster if the extra column was created?

Comment: No, it would just waste some space.

Comment: oh wait! I just tried it out and got this SQL Error [42P17]: ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Comment: Sorry. I have changed my answer to make the function immutable.

Comment: What if you are searching against multiple columns on the same table? Do you need an index for each table or a single index for all of them?

Comment: @ZeroDivide That depends on your query. The index has to be on the same expression that is in your query. If in doubt, ask a new question (or search for existing answers).

Answer (score 1):

The postgreSQL documentation seems to suggest that it is indeed faster to use a separate tsvector column:

> One advantage of the separate-column approach over an expression index is that it is not necessary to explicitly specify the text search configuration in queries in order to make use of the index. As shown in the example above, the query can depend on default_text_search_config. **Another advantage is that searches will be faster, since it will not be necessary to redo the to_tsvector calls to verify index matches.** The expression-index approach is simpler to set up, however, and it requires less disk space since the tsvector representation is not stored explicitly.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html